# cakePHP & Twitter Bootstrap - View

Tags: cakephp, layout, twitter-bootstrap, routes, scaffold

I'm using this plugin with CakePHP --> [TwitterBootstrap](https://github.com/slywalker/TwitterBootstrap), everything works like a glow except I can't change the layouts. ie. index, add and such.

I have a model called Cinema and have created this with cake bake and the same thing with Views/Cinemas

This is my controller:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
/**
 * Cinemas Controller
 *
 */
class CinemasController extends AppController {

/**
 *  Layout
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $layout = 'bootstrap';

/**
 * Scaffold
 *
 * @var mixed
 */
    public $scaffold;

}
```

Have i overridden CakePHPs routes into some special scaffolding template?

Comment: View/Scaffolds
I added index.ctp there and everything worked, now I have removed public $scaffold and my original index works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By defining `public $scaffold;` in your controller, you tell Cake that you want to enable [Scaffolding](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/scaffolding.html) mode, which allows you to easily insert/edit/delete some records. The scaffolding mode always uses your "default" layout.

In other words, by defining the `public $scaffold;` variable, you "overrule" your layout. Scaffolding mode doesn't adopt that setting. Simply remove the `public $scaffold;` line to get back to your bootstrap layout.

Comment: Where is that scaffolding page located? I mean the default one?

Comment: @Philip app/View/Layouts/default.ctp